# How does one verify if a vector is really recovered?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization, signal-processing

In [compressed sensing](http://dsp.rice.edu/cs), how to verify if a vector is really recovered or how does one plot the figures on recovery rate? Since in numerical experiments, there is always a difference between the original vector and the vector produced by compressed sensing algorithms.

Comment: Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some context or examples for the benefit of people not intimately familiar with compressed sensing?

Answer (score 1):

Given the original sparse representation of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ over a dictionary $D_{n \times n}$, i.e. a sparse vector $s\in \mathbb{R}^n$ , you project $x$ over $m$ random i.i.d. subgaussian vectors (the rows of a matrix $A_{m \times n}$, usually i.i.d. Gaussian or symmetric Bernoulli) so that $$y = A x = A D s \in \mathbb{R}^m$$
with $m < n$.
Optimization by linear programming yields $$\hat{s} = \min_{s \in \mathbb{R}^n} ||s||_1$$ $$s.t.$$ $$y = A D s$$

If the number of measurements $m \geq C k \log (n/k)$, where $k$ is the sparsity (the cardinality of the support of the original $s$), then $$||s - \hat{s}||^2_2$$ will be small because the sparsest solution is also the minimum $\ell_1$ solution for the given underdetermined linear system $y = A D s$.

As for performance figures, for a fixed $n$ you can plot the average reconstruction error $\mathbf{E}[||s - \hat{s}||^2_2]$ (or the SNR) over a Monte Carlo of sparse random vectors $s$ and measurement matrices $A$ for various $m$ and $k$. This may be misleading though, because it mixes low-error or perfect instances with critical instances for low values of $m$.

Another more effective alternative is plotting the probability $P(||s - \hat{s}||^2_2 > \zeta)$ with $\zeta$ a small precision threshold (e.g. $10^{-6}$), which is the probability of successful reconstruction, and count the number of instances in a Monte Carlo batch which are above/below this threshold. By plotting the PSR you should see a sharp phase transition phenomenon which has been studied [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5458001).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it depends on the signal under consideration.

E.g.
Images

```
   PSNR for recovery or denoising.
   SSIM for structural similarity in segmentation problem.
   Edginess inrange image super-resolution.
```

Speech

```
   PESQ objective scores.
   MOS  subjective score or listener's test
   WER word error rate in reconstructed speech.
```

ECG, EEG

```
 SDR signal to distortion ratio
```

Apart for these in general average reconstruction error using ecludian norm, spectral difference etc.